# Problems with while and switch loops

Tags: c++, while-loop, switch-statement

I'm having issues with my code. I am trying to build a game and it somehow gives errors when reaching the main loops. I will show to code and the errors I'm getting.

Just a small note, the point when choosing option 1 and playing the game is that the game loops after the correct answer has been given and presents the player with a second random word, and keeps doing this until the player writes 'quit'.

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    enum fields {WORD, HINT, NUM_FIELDS};
    const int NUM_WORDS = 3;
    const string WORDS[NUM_WORDS][NUM_FIELDS] =
    {
        {"jumble1", "First word."},
        {"jumble2", "Second word."},
        {"jumble3", "Third word."}
    };

    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    int choice = (rand() % NUM_WORDS);
    string theWord = WORDS[choice][WORD];
    string theHint = WORDS[choice][HINT];

    string jumble = theWord;
    int length = jumble.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        int index1 = (rand() % length);
        int index2 = (rand() % length);
        char temp = jumble[index1];
        jumble[index1] = jumble[index2];
        jumble[index2] = temp;
    }

    int choice;
    bool choiceNotMade = true;

    while (choiceNotMade)
    {
        cout << "[1] Play\n";
        cout << "[2] Credits\n";
        cout << "[3] Quit\n\n";

                cout << "Your choice: ";
        cin >> choice;
        }

            switch (choice)
            {
            case 1:
                cout << "Unscramble the letters to make a word.\n";
                cout << "Enter 'hint' for a hint.\n";
                cout << "Enter 'quit' to quit the game.\n\n";
                cout << "The jumble is: " << jumble;

                string guess;
                cout << "\n\nYour guess: ";
                cin >> guess;

                while ((guess != theWord) && (guess != "quit"))
                {
                    if (guess == "hint")
                    {
                        cout << theHint;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << "That's not the right word.";
                    }

                    cout << "\n\nYour guess: ";
                    cin >> guess;
                }

                if (guess == theWord)
                {
                    cout << "\nYou guessed it!\n";
                }

                cout << "\nThank you for playing.\n";

                system("Pause");
                choiceNotMade = false;
                break;

            case 2:
                cout << "\n\nThis game has been made by:\n\n";
                choiceNotMade = false;
                break;

            case 3:
                cout << "Program will exit";
                exit(1);

            default:
                cout << "\nYou did not pick a valid option.\n\n";
                choiceNotMade = false;
                break;  

                } 

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the error:

```
word_jumble.cpp: In function `int main()':
word_jumble.cpp:32: error: redeclaration of `int choice'
word_jumble.cpp:17: error: `int choice' previously declared here
word_jumble.cpp:83: error: jump to case label
word_jumble.cpp:53: error:   crosses initialization of `std::string guess'
word_jumble.cpp:88: error: jump to case label
word_jumble.cpp:53: error:   crosses initialization of `std::string guess'
word_jumble.cpp:92: error: jump to case label
word_jumble.cpp:53: error:   crosses initialization of `std::string guess'
word_jumble.cpp:83: warning: destructor needed for `guess'
word_jumble.cpp:83: warning: where case label appears here
word_jumble.cpp:83: warning: (enclose actions of previous case statements requiring destructors in their own scope.)
word_jumble.cpp:88: warning: destructor needed for `guess'
word_jumble.cpp:88: warning: where case label appears here
word_jumble.cpp:92: warning: destructor needed for `guess'
word_jumble.cpp:92: warning: where case label appears here
word_jumble.cpp:100:2: warning: no newline at end of file
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/word_jumble.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the message

> redeclaration of `int choice'

should be pretty obvious.

The other error messages are a little harder to understand, but will disappear if you declare the variable `guess` outside of the `switch` statement.

Comment: @user1222107 I don't know the technical details, but it has to do with that case labels doesn't create new blocks. The solution is either to declare all variables outside the `switch` statement, or put them in a `{}` block. You can do something like `case X: { /* stuff */ }` and have variables declared inside.

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring `int choice` twice. The error message is pretty clear on that.

Once you've declared a variable, you can't re-declare it in the same scope:

```
{
  int x;

  //...
  int x; // <-- illegal, just use x
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `choice` at two places. Also, you have written the `switch` outside the `while` loop which means that even if your program compiles, it will be stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Do you see `choiceNotMade` getting set to `false` in the `while`?

Comment: It doesn't matter, because alternative 3 in the `switch` calls `exit`, and `choiceNotMade` is set to `false` in alternative 2.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I was talking about the switch statement written outside the `while (choiceNotMade)` loop which will certainly lead to an infinite loop. By looking at the indentation, it looks as if the intention was to write the switch within that loop.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, missed a `}` due to the indentation.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I don't see how the program would even reach the `switch` when the `while` loop doesn't terminate.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that this is a homework, so I'll stay away from too specific recommendations.

You declared the variable `choice` on line 19, so you need to remove the second declaration at line 34.

You also need to move the declaration of `string guess` to before the `switch` statement. This is because C++ requires all locals to be initialized exactly once, and there is no way a compiler could make sure of that if the first time through the loop you take `case 2:` and the second time around it takes `case 1:` where `string guess` is declared.

This will make your program compile, but it would not work as expected. Look at the opening/closing braces in your program, and ensure that the code blocks are nested in the way that you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring

```
int choice;
```

twice, once

```
int choice = (rand() % NUM_WORDS);
```

and then, right before

```
while (choiceNotMade)
```